# Retrieve an html code from database and store it in a javascript variable (with no escaping)

Tags: javascript, django

An html code is stored in database, for example:

```html
<p>django is <strong>good</strong></p>
```

In the template when I want to store it in a javascript variable, it store with escaped mode and the javascript `unescape` function is not helpful.

Comment: your question isn't helpful either. if you want help unescaping it then we need to see the code that is causing it to be escaped.. or at least the escaped version of the markup.

Comment: What code have you written already? Please have a read of [this guide on producing code for a good quality question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), then include and mark up your code in your question. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you render the result in the template, use the "safe" template tag to give you the result you're looking for.

The docs for using this are here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/builtins/#safe

Comment: Thank you! You saved my life! I have forgotten this point! Thank you!!